# Eclipse flickering on new line

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, gtk3

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Eclipse Neon. Everything looks OK but when i press enter, the new line flickering. Switching to the GTK2 solved the problem but i have some other issue in GTK2 such as scroll bar coloring and button coloring in the Dark theme.

Since I don't have any problem in GTK3 and the flickering is the only problem i have, how can i fix it in GTK3?

here you can see how it flicker in GTK3

[image: Eclipse flicker in GTK3]

**EDIT**

Recently I tried Eclipse Neon.3 on Ubuntu Gnome, but the problem still exist. It Seems it's not the Unity problem.

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Comment: @rpax No.  I still have the problem :(

Comment: If you post this question in stackoverflow, I'll put a bounty on it.

Comment: @rpax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147840/eclipse-flickering-on-new-line